# py2app and python 2.7 OSX 10.6

Tags: macos, py2app, python-2.7

Does py2app work with python 2.7 on Snow Leopard?

I can't even get a 'hello world' to compile properly.
Here's what I'm doing...

My script is

```
print "Hello World"
```

and then from a terminal:

```
cd myFolder
py2applet --make-setup helloWorld.py myIcon.icns
python setup.py py2app
```

The build hangs indefinitely at this point. If I add the -A switch it will build, but crashes with a Tick Count error.
If I edit the setup.py file and set argv_emulation to 'False' it'll build with the -A option and work (still hangs indefinitely without the -A).
So my real question is:

How can I get this to build without the -A option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though py2app had some issues with the 32/64-bit install of python 2.7 I was using (the official one from python.org).
I downloaded a 32-bit only version of 2.7 and it works now.

On a related note, on another build I was using wxPython and to get it to work without the -A switch I had to import the package explicitly in my setup.py file.

```
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'packages' : ['wx', 'pubsub'],

          }
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the correct one. :)  Thanks for figuring this out.  I was running into the same problem and it was driving me crazy.

Comment: whoops; forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that you need to leave the 'argv_emulation': True setting out of the options for a 64bit build.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The default is auto-generated as 'True', if I recall. Do you mean edit the setup.py file and remove that option entirely?